# Efficient way to migrate a pruned node

Tags: synchronization, nodes, raspberry-pi, pruning

I would like to know what are the step to succefully migrate a pruned node.

I have a Raspnode (rPi2B+) and it is so slow that it doesnt seem to sync the blockchain after several days...

I want to sync the node that I have in my laptop and move it (pruned) to the Raspnode.

I have copy and paste all the files in the .bitcoin folder and when I execute the `bitcoind -daemon` command the follow is in the debug.log file

```
2016-03-22 23:25:55 Opening LevelDB in /home/pi/bitcoinData/blocks/index
2016-03-22 23:25:59 Opened LevelDB successfully
2016-03-22 23:25:59 Opening LevelDB in /home/pi/bitcoinData/chainstate
2016-03-22 23:25:59 Opened LevelDB successfully
2016-03-22 23:26:37 LoadBlockIndexDB: last block file = 474
2016-03-22 23:26:45 LoadBlockIndexDB: last block file info: CBlockFileInfo(blocks=57, size=47829393, heights=403730...403810, time=2016-03-22..$
2016-03-22 23:26:48 Checking all blk files are present...
2016-03-22 23:26:48 LoadBlockIndexDB(): Block files have previously been pruned
2016-03-22 23:26:48 LoadBlockIndexDB: transaction index disabled
2016-03-22 23:26:49 LoadBlockIndexDB: hashBestChain=000000000000000005323717f768df54444ee6dfccbe080548287f120546e6e3 height=403810 date=2016-03$
2016-03-22 23:26:49 init message: Verifying blocks...
2016-03-22 23:26:49 Verifying last 288 blocks at level 3
2016-03-22 23:26:51 LevelDB read failure: Corruption: not an sstable (bad magic number)
2016-03-22 23:27:14 Corruption: not an sstable (bad magic number)
2016-03-22 23:27:14 : Error opening block database.

Do you want to rebuild the block database now?
2016-03-22 23:27:14 Aborted block database rebuild. Exiting.
2016-03-22 23:27:14 Shutdown: In progress...
2016-03-22 23:27:14 scheduler thread interrupt
2016-03-22 23:27:14 StopNode()
2016-03-22 23:27:14 Shutdown: done
2016-03-22 23:39:01 AppInit2 : parameter interaction: -prune -> setting -disablewallet=1
2016-03-22 23:39:05 Prune configured to target 30000MiB on disk for block and undo files.
2016-03-22 23:39:08
```

The idea is to sync the node in my laptop and then maintain the syncing (and pruning) on the rapsberry pi because I cant run the node all the time in my laptop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copying .bitcoin folder should work. Make sure bitcoind is not running (try ps -ef | grep bitcoin)  before you attempt to copy. Also make sure bitcoin.conf is same in both places

Also, change the bitcoin.conf file with the new **datadir** , **rpcuser** and **rpcpassword**

Comment: Is it safe to share pruned data? If I just want to sync a 500M pruned node can I download the pruned data from a node with the same configuration? In order to get a new node synced ASAP.

Comment: @pinhead it should work but I am not sure, if you have done it and it works please update it here. Thanks